# How to extract text from pdf using golang?

Tags: go, pdf, text-extraction

I am trying to extract text from a pdf file in golang. See the code below. For some reason, it's printing complete garbage(some random numbers). [Here](https://aitatennis.com/management/upload/ranking/2023-04-24_BU-12.pdf) is the pdf. I believe it's possible to extract text since I am able to copy and paste the text from this file.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    pdf "github.com/unidoc/unipdf/v3/model"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter URL of PDF file:")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    url, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    url = strings.TrimSpace(url)

    // Fetch PDF from URL.
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    buf, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    pdfReader, err := pdf.NewPdfReader(bytes.NewReader(buf))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Parse PDF file.
    isEncrypted, err := pdfReader.IsEncrypted()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // If PDF is encrypted, exit with message.
    if isEncrypted {
        fmt.Println("Error: PDF is encrypted.")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Get number of pages.
    numPages, err := pdfReader.GetNumPages()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Iterate through pages and print text.
    for i := 1; i <= numPages; i++ {
        page, err := pdfReader.GetPage(i)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        text, err := page.GetAllContentStreams()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for `GetAllContentStreams` might returns formats, graphics, images, and other objects in that page and that might be the reason for printing complete garbage(some random numbers).

> GetAllContentStreams gets all the content streams for a page as one
> string

Instead of `GetAllContentStreams`, we can use `ExtractText` method to extract the text.

> ExtractText processes and extracts all text data in content streams
> and returns as a string.

And this should need a [licence](https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf-examples/tree/master/license) api key to use the package.

https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf

> This software package (unipdf) is a commercial product and requires a
> license code to operate.
>
> To Get a Metered License API Key in for free in the Free Tier, sign up
> on https://cloud.unidoc.io

The unipdf example code can be found at [here](https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf-examples/blob/master/extract/pdf_simple_extraction.go)

Here is the updated code

```
func init() {
    // Make sure to load your metered License API key prior to using the library.
    // If you need a key, you can sign up and create a free one at https://cloud.unidoc.io
    err := license.SetMeteredKey("your-metered-api-key")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    //
    // The other blocks in your code
    //

    // Iterate through pages and print text.
    for i := 1; i <= numPages; i++ {
        pageNum := i + 1

        page, err := pdfReader.GetPage(i)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        ex, err := extractor.New(page)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        text, err := ex.ExtractText()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("------------------------------")
        fmt.Printf("Page %d:\n", pageNum)
        fmt.Printf(text)
        fmt.Println("------------------------------")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any free solution like we have PyPDF2 in Python?

Comment: @simplfuzz One of the free solution is to use the `pdftotext` tool. See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I can not find a free, capable Go package to extract text from PDF. Luckily, there are some free CLI tools that can do this.

`pdftotext` from [Xpdf](http://www.xpdfreader.com/about.html) is a promising choice. See its output:

```
$ pdftotext -layout -nopgbrk 2023-04-24_BU-12.pdf - | head
                           ALL INDIA TENNIS ASSOCIATION
                                        As on 24TH April , 2023
       BOY'S UNDER-12                                 2011                BEST    BEST    25% BEST POINTS
       24TH April , 2023                                                  Eight   Eight     Eight  CUT FOR     TTL.
                                                                          SING.   DBLS.     DBLS. NO SHOW      PTS.
RANK   NAME OF PLAYER                     REG NO.      DOB       STATE     PTS.   PTS.       PTS.  LATE WL    Final
  1    VIVAAN MIRDHA                      432735    08-Apr-11      (RJ)    485     565     141.25     0        797
  2    SMIT SACHIN UNDRE                  437763    07-Feb-11    (MH)      435     480       120      0      664.25
  3    RISHIKESH MANE                     436806    15-Jan-11    (MH)      420     380        95      0        619
  4    VIRAJ CHOUDHARY                    436648    03-Feb-11      (DL)    415     420       105      0      598.75
```

On Ubuntu, this tool can be installed with this command:

```
$ sudo apt install poppler-utils
```

And it's easy to execute it from Go application with the `exec` package:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    // See "man pdftotext" for more options.
    args := []string{
        "-layout",              // Maintain (as best as possible) the original physical layout of the text.
        "-nopgbrk",             // Don't insert page breaks (form feed characters) between pages.
        "2023-04-24_BU-12.pdf", // The input file.
        "-",                    // Send the output to stdout.
    }
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(context.Background(), "pdftotext", args...)

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &buf

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```